# Validate Edit field when visibility changes of field

Tags: android, validation

Trying to validate 3 edit field.
 At first field 1 is visible and after entering text in 1 field 2 becomes visible (after Clicking on add more button) and so on. 
Now i have got stuck on field validation.

Here is what i have tried:

Get fields:

```
final EditText status = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_field);
final EditText status2 = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_field1);
final EditText status3 = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_field2);
```

Listeners:

```
status.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {                               

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
         enableSubmitIfReady();
    }

    public void enableSubmitIfReady() 
    {
       boolean Ready =status.getText().toString().length()>0;

       if (Ready) 
       {
            ADD_MORE.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ADD_MORE.setEnabled(true);
       } else {
            ADD_MORE.setEnabled(false);  
       }
    }
});
```

.

```
status2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        enableSubmitIfReady();
    }

    public void enableSubmitIfReady() 
    {
        boolean isReady =status.getText().toString().length()>0;

        if (isReady) {
            ADD_MORE.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ADD_MORE.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ADD_MORE.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
});
```

.

```
status3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        ADD_MORE.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        disable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

.

```
                ADD_MORE.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(status.getText().toString().length()>0)
                        {   
                        second_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                         if(status2.getText().toString().length()>0)
                        {
                        third_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                    }
                });
```

.

```
               OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    String status_message = status.getText().toString();
                    String status_message2 = status2.getText().toString();
                    String status_message3 = status3.getText().toString();
                    Boolean isVisible,isvisible ;
                    isVisible = second_layout.isShown();
                    isvisible = third_layout.isShown();
                    if(status_message.matches(""))
                    {
                        MessageDialog.showMessage("Alert!",
                                "Please enter atleast one charcter", VideoPlaybackActivity.screen);
                        status.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(status_message2.matches("") & isVisible.equals("true"))
                    {
                        MessageDialog.showMessage("Alert!",
                                "Please enter atleast one charcter", VideoPlaybackActivity.screen);
                        status2.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(status_message3.matches("") & isvisible.equals("true"))
                    {
                        MessageDialog.showMessage("Alert!",
                                "Please enter atleast one charcter", VideoPlaybackActivity.screen);
                        status3.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tag.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);  
                    }
                }
            });
```

for more please see image....(2 and 3 are invisible initially )
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Add edit text field dynamically**

```
//this is your main layout element where you want to add new edittext
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mycontent); 
LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getBaseContext() .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
//This what you want to add so creat new layout for edittext
EditText addView = layoutInflater .inflate(R.layout.addlayout, null); 
//call this method on button click
ll.addView(addView);
```

**Here is new Edittext layout (addlayout):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sepmain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Add"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Tag"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/new"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

*For more understand dynamic views,check below link:*
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html